# Publish Reconcile branch version using ArcPy as web tool return editing error result

Tags: arcpy, versioning, reconcile

The return message is shown below:

1. Starting reconcile.
2. Reconciling version USER.MyVersion with SDE.DEFAULT.
3. Warning: Error starting editing on version USER.MyVersion.
4. 1 of 1 versions finished.
5. Finished reconcile.

I try to use ArcGIS Pro to run the script it return no error. However when publish script as web tool and execute it returns starting editing on version error.

```
import arcpy, sys, datetime, os, tempfile, shutil
from arcpy import env

def main():
    
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

    
    url = "https://mysite.mydomain/server/rest/services/ElectricNetwork/FeatureServer"
    version = "USER.MyVersion"
    post_desc = "N"
    portal_user = "user"
    portal_pwd = "password"
    portal_url = "portal_url"

    outputResult = "Reconcile Failed"
    
    with_post = "NO_POST"
    
    if post_desc == "Y":
        with_post = "POST"
        
    workspace = url 

    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    arcpy.SignInToPortal(portal_url, portal_user, portal_pwd)
    
    reconcileLog = r'C:\NewFolder\Reconcile_Log.txt'

    try:
        result = arcpy.ReconcileVersions_management(workspace, 
                                "ALL_VERSIONS", 
                                "SDE.DEFAULT", 
                                version, 
                                "LOCK_ACQUIRED", 
                                "ABORT_CONFLICTS", 
                                "BY_OBJECT", 
                                "FAVOR_EDIT_VERSION", 
                                with_post, 
                                "KEEP_VERSION", 
                                reconcileLog)
    except:
        reconcileMessage = "Reconcile failed:  " + arcpy.GetMessages() + ".  Check reconcilelog.txt file in the " + str(reconcileLog)
        arcpy.AddWarning(reconcileMessage)

    
    if len(result.getMessages(1)) > 0 :                
        arcpy.AddWarning ((result.getMessages(1)))
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage ("Version reconciled successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```